# Creating an instance from a type parameter in scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, pattern-matching

I am writing a small calculator in scala as a learning exercise.

I have a `BinExpr[T]` class which represents a binary expression of type T.

The full signature is as follows:

```
abstract sealed class Expr()
abstract sealed class BinExpr[T <: BinExpr[T]](val v1: Expr, val v2: Expr) extends Expr
```

I have a replace function that replaces a variable (a string symbol in an expression) with a literal.

```
def replace(e: Expr, s: Var, t: Lit): Expr = e match {
  case v: Var if v.symbol == s.symbol => t
  case v: Var => v
  case l: Lit => l
  case b: BinExpr[T] => new T(replace(b.v1, s, t), replace(b.v2, s, t))
}
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
calculator.scala:31: error: not found: type T
  case b: BinExpr[T] => new T(replace(b.v1, s, t), replace(b.v2, s, t))
                 ^
calculator.scala:31: error: not found: type T
  case b: BinExpr[T] => new T(replace(b.v1, s, t), replace(b.v2, s, t))
```

I understand that type erasure causes the `T` not to be available at runtime. That said, `BinExpr[T]` is a sealed class. Therefore, `T` can only be one of a small number of types, which are known at compile time. It seems to me that this case should just be expanded to capture those values of `T`. Clearly this is not the case. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

How about putting a factory method on `BinExpr` so that each subclass knows how to instantiate itself, given two new parameters.  Here's a simplified example:

```
trait A {
  def make(a: Int, b: Int): A
}
class B(x: Int, y: Int) extends A {
  def make(a: Int, b: Int) = new B(x, y)
}
class C(x: Int, y: Int) extends A {
  def make(a: Int, b: Int) = new C(x, y)
}

def f(x: A): A = x match {
  case a: A => a.make(1, 2)
}


val b = f(new B(5, 6))
val c = f(new C(5, 6))
```

Comment: Isn't it makes *one more* instance of desired class?

Comment: Matching on `x` feels rather pointless, when we know that x is an instance of `A`.